# How do I sum a column based on two conditions, one based on field value, the other based upon retrieved record's values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list like the one below from which I'm looking to aggregate the sum in the "amount" column for a given company. The trick of the matter is that I want to include family members of employees of the company. Those relations are kept by the ID to the right and will differ by the 12th character (if the family in question only has one member, then the 12th character is a space).

[image: Sample Data]

My question is, what is the most efficient way to get the amount for all employees of ABC Inc, including family members. I believe that this will require first one query for all employees of ABC Inc, then another for their family members by using the resulting list from query one.

Is this the most efficient way to do this? My table is extremely large (over 10GB of flat data), and thousands of such queries will be required, so efficiency is important.

The code I'm using thus far to get the data without family members is:

```
select ID, Name, Company_Name,  sum(Amount) from indivs
where Orgname ='APC Inc' --or Employer like '%APC Inc%'
group by ID, Name,  Company_Name
```

However, this only gives me the amounts from the direct employees.

What would be the next step to add the amounts for family members?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select sum(amount)
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.company = 'APC Inc.' and
                    left(t2.id, 11) = left(t.id, 11)
             );
```

For performance, you can create a computed column and index:

```
alter table t add id11 as (left(id, 11)) persisted;

create index idx_company_id11 on t(company, id11);
```

Then phrase the query as:

```
select sum(amount)
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.company = 'APC Inc.' and
                    t2.id11 = t.id11
             );
```